# Reducing step count in regex for a year terminator

Tags: c#, regex, passwords

I've got a question regarding regular expression step counts in discovering a year near or at the end of a string.

Take a string like:

**Chocolatechipcookie2017!**

Finding the year at the end is not really the problem, there are tonnes of options to go with. Some faster than others. All of them, however, have a reasonably high step count.

Take, for instance:

```
\d{2,}\b.{0,1}$
```

Step count: 24

Or:

```
\d{2,}.{0,1}$
```

Step count: 23

Or (not my favourite one):

```
$(?<=\d\d.)
```

Step count: 31

Or the more precise:

```
[12]{0,1}\d{2,3}.{0,1}$
```

Step count: 43

So far, the fastest:

```
^.*\d{2,}.{0,1}$
```

Step count: 10

What I'd like to accomplish is to reduce the step count as much as possible. In short strings such as my example, the problem isn't too severe but my password manager can and will happily generate passwords of an arbitrary length and there are services out there that do actually support passwords up to or possibly even over 512 characters in length.

Also, I do have a sort of academic interest in it. So even if the real world scenario of my password manager does not matter too much, I would still like to hear some thoughts on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, what are the requirements? Just find the last 4 digit streak in a string before an optional char? If the digits are really always close to the end, the quickest solution with regex is via capturing them, like in [`^.*(\d{4}).?$`](https://regex101.com/r/m2J0WM/1). However, this step count is only a relative metric that does not really prove a regex is worse or better (especially if the difference is like in your examples). Moreover, .NET regex engine is just very powerful, and where PCRE gets stuck, .NET one may go through.

Comment: Basically, yeah. Find something that is probably a year at or near the end of a string. People tend to still maintain the habbit of creating passwords in that vain, WordWordYear(PossibleSymbol). Also, I am just keen on understanding regex itself better, to see what optimizations exist and how to use those optimizations.

Comment: In .NET, you may greatly enhance this by using `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` modifier. And just use `@"[0-9]{4}"`. You should not worry about steps - this is by far superior than trying to "tweak" anything with the traditional left-to-right string parsing.

Comment: Without the ltr option mentioned by @WiktorStribiżew, I believe the quickest is `^.*(\d{4})` - 17 steps (since it's greedy it'll grab the last result it finds). I'm not sure C# supports this next one (`\K` is used), however, `^.*\K\d{4}` is the fastest I could come up with - 16 steps

Comment: Besides, use http://regexhero.net/tester to see the .NET regex speed in iterations per second. Do not use regex101.com, it just does not support .NET regex engine.

Comment: @ctwheels: Whereas greed is indeed a contributing and helpful factor to take into account, your approach will still match if I append more stuff to the end of the example string. You did however give me a minor idea, which I'll add to the possible regular expressions in my question.

Comment: @zdQTJEnZ it seems the *best* answer is `^.*([0-9]{4})` while using `RegexOptions.RightToLeft`. This yields the best benchmark results on regexhero and least steps on regex101. Benchmark results are around 1.5 times better than any other code mentioned before this comment and it uses 17 steps.

Comment: You cannot use `^.*(\d{4})` with RTL - it will get the first 4 digit number. The only suitable fastest pattern is `[0-9]{4}` with RTL option. Or `\d{4}` (but remember that in .NET `\d` matches all Unicode digits, or use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to only match ASCII digits with `\d`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Steps

*Step counter using regex101*

```
^.*(\d{4})        17
^.*\K\d{4}        16
\d{4}             23
```

**Note:** The second option above doesn't work in C# as well as many other regex flavours.

---

### Benchmark

#### Benchmarks - RegexHero

**Note:** Benchmarks may differ from system to system.

```
^.*(\d{4})           ~915,000/s
^.*([0-9]{4})        ~1,030,000/s
\d{4}                ~693,000/s
[0-9]{4}             ~910,000/s
```

Using `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` as mentioned by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

```
^.*(\d{4})           ~1,233,000/s
^.*([0-9]{4})        ~1,340,000/s
\d{4}                ~698,000/s
[0-9]{4}             ~909,000/s
```

Clearly using the right to left option increases performance for our use-case.

The image below shows a comparison of benchmarks while using the `RightToLeft` option. The first 10 results are for the `[0-9]{4}` regex, and the last 10 are for the `^.*([0-9]{4})` regex.

[image: Benchmark results]

#### Benchmarks - Code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            List<string> regexes = new List<string> {
                @"[0-9]{4}",
                @"^.*([0-9]{4})"
            };

            foreach (string regex in regexes)
            {
                List<TimeSpan> times = new List<TimeSpan>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    stopwatch.Start();

                    Regex myRegex = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                    string strTargetString = @"Chocolatechipcookie2017!";

                    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
                    {
                        foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    times.Add(stopwatch.Elapsed);
                }
                TimeSpan average = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(times.Average(t => t.TotalMilliseconds));
                Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed={average}");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code **with `RightToLeft` option enabled**:

- `[0-9]{4}`: 3.710 seconds
- `^.*([0-9]{4})`: 10.276 seconds

The above code **without `RightToLeft`**:

- `[0-9]{4}`: 3.523 seconds
- `^.*([0-9]{4})`: 10.956 seconds

---

### Answer

According to the step counter and benchmark results obtained by RegexHero, the best performing regex is `^.*([0-9]{4})` with the `RightToLeft` option enabled.

Based on the benchmark results using the code above, the best performing regex is `[0-9]{4}` without the `RightToLeft` option enabled.

**Note**: These tests simply test the speed at which the regexes perform and do not take into account performance of data operations that follow the initial regex execution.

Comment: [`[0-9]{4}` / `\d{4}` with RTL is the fastest](https://ideone.com/4FP2l9). Always test in the target environment.

Comment: Too bad I can't run Regex Hero myself, this benchmark functionality looks awesome. But, Wine does not support .NET nearly well enough to run something like that. ;)

Comment: With `^.*[0-9]{4}`, you can't extract the digits. A capturing group always hampers down performance. This comparison compares apples to oranges. Besides, there is no point to use RegexHero for this case, we only are interested in the first occurrence, it returns all occurrences.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My apologies, typo. I'm getting better performance with the anchor using the capture group

Comment: @ctwheels Where is your testing code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew testing performed in regexhero (downloaded onto Windows desktop) `foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(targetString))
{
  string text = match.Value;
}` (according to the regexhero application)

Comment: Ok, as I said, the best efficiency test must be run in the target environment. Besides, always compare apples to apples, `^.*\d{4}` does not match the same as `\d{4}` with RTL modifier. And yes, RegexHero looks for all matches. We are only interested in the first match (`Regex.Match`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for pointing that out. I created a C# program to test the regexes against one another. You are correct, `[0-9]{4}` does perform better, however, that's without using the `RightToLeft` option

Comment: @ctwheels -- If I could add another upvote, I would. Because that answer is now just absolutely legendary. Really, even other regular expression performance related questions will benefit from it. Solid work. I tip my hat to you, in respect.

Comment: @zdQTJEnZ to be honest my initial answer was lazy haha I only improved it cause Wiktor made me, but I do appreciate that he did as it helps me to answer questions more appropriately and with better care & precision